# Adding command arguments to the Django runserver command and handle() method setup for local secure HTTP server

Tags: django, manage.py, django-2.1

I'll keep this as vague as possible - as it's quite a broad question.

I'm building a payment system within my Django project - and it would be amazing to be able to run my project over a secure server connections. And now were moving into a more forced secure internet with more emphasis on site security with in browser alerts etc I think this is something that needs to be added to the Django core management commands.

I've started to build this functionality inside an application:

`management/commands/runsecureserver.py`:

```
import os
import ssl
import sys

from django.core.servers.basehttp import WSGIServer

class SecureHTTPServer(WSGIServer):
    def __init__(self, address, handler_cls, certificate, key):
        super(SecureHTTPServer, self).__init__(address, handler_cls)
        self.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(self.socket, certfile=certificate,
                                      keyfile=key, server_side=True,
                                      ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
                                      cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

I'm now wondering - I have the following class that extends from the `BaseCommand` class from Django's `runserver.py` where I add my arguments for specifying cert files etc, an `inner_run()` function which will mimic a lot of the Django runserver `inner_run()` with added certificate checks, port configurations etc.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super(Command, self).add_arguments(parser)
        parser.add_argument(**some argument here***)
```

However, when running:

```
$ python manage.py runsecureserver
```

I receive the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseCommand must provide a handle() method
```

So, it's telling me I need a `handle()` method...

Q. What is a handle() method in this context, and what should it do?

Q. Is it enough to simply use the existing `handle()` method from Django's `runserver.py`?

Comment: A quick question regarding SSL. Why not run it behind a web server like nginx? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TGO Just out of laziness really of moving everything to a staging server, and it helps learn the core Django infrastructure. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Your file must be within /DjangoProject/YouApp/management/commands/

```py
# custom_command.py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--delta')
        parser.add_argument('--alpha')
        parser.add_argument('--universe')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # argument in a dict here :
        print(options)

        # Do your stuff :)
        pass
```

```sh
python manage.py custom_command --universe=42
```